# Is it hard to find m, R to make RG^H(m||R)=C?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, discrete-logarithm

Assuming the generator of one group $\mathbb G$ is $G$. Given an element $C\in \mathbb G$ and a cryptographic hash function $H(\cdot)$, is it hard for one adversary to find a pair of message $m$ and another element $R\in \mathbb G$ to make $RG^{H(m||R)}=C$?

Besides, is it necessary to make $H(\cdot)$ become the random oracle (RO)?

Intuitively, finding such a pair of $m$ and $R$ is hard, but I want to prove it formally.

Comment: I think you can safely strip out $m$ from the equation if $H(\cdot)$ is a random oracle. It should be easy to prove that $H': G^H(R)$ results in a uniform distribution. In the end then it comes down to finding $R \cdot H'(R) = C$ which is computationally hard (by contraposition, if it weren't hard then H would obviously break pre-image resistance). Uh, that's my "intuition" . Now for the person that writes that down in mathematical notation.

Comment: If $H(\cdot)$ is not a random oracle then it is not providing a uniform distribution. This means that H' won't give that either, and it would have implications for the security; in that case $m$ could start to matter. It does complicate matters as now the question becomes: how does the construction of H affect the distribution of the output? I'd choose a modern hash function that is not afflicted by attacks, preferably including length extension attacks. Proving security otherwise would go above my abilities for sure.

Comment: Assume that we can find distinct pairs $(m_1,R_1)$ and $(m_2,R_2)$ such that

$$ R_1G^{H(m_1||R_1)} =  R_2G^{H(m_2||R_2)}=C $$ in a different view

$$ G^{H(m_1||R_1)} =  R'G^{H(m_2||R_2)} $$ So, in a manner you are asking a different collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume

- $\mathbb G$ is a finite group of order $g$
- the hash's output is an integer in range $[0,h)$
- both $g$ and $h$ are super-polynomial in the security parameter $k$ (this is necessary for the problem to be hard, because if $H(m\mathbin\|C)\bmod g=0$ then $(m,C)$ is a solution, thus if $H$ is a random oracle then trying $(m,C)$ with random $m$ has probability $\lceil h/g\rceil/h$ of success, which is non-negligible if either $g$ or $h$ is non-negligible).
- $H$ and $C$ are defined independently (if we can choose $C$ knowing $H$ or alter $H$ knowing $C$, then the problem is trivial).

Since $\mathbb G$ has a generator, it is isomorphic to integers modulo $g$ under addition, that I'll note $(\mathbb Z_g,+)$, with an isomorphism $f:\mathbb Z_g\to\mathbb G$, $f(x)=G^x$. It's such that $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$. Notice that $f^{-1}$ is well-defined, if not necessarily easy to compute.

The equation $R\,G^{H(m\mathbin\|R)}=C$ is equivalent to
$$H(m\mathbin\|R)\bmod g\ =\ (f^{-1}(C)-f^{-1}(R))\bmod g$$
Therefore, if $H$ is a random oracle, then for any $R$, the probability that a $m$ verifies the equation is a nonincreasing function of the right side, thus maximum when the right side is $0$, thus at most $\lceil h/g\rceil/h$, thus negligible. Thus any query to the oracle has negligible probability to yield a solution. Thus the problem is hard.

I do not know if we can conclude with just the hypothesis that $H$ is preimage-resistant and collision-resistant. I do not rule out that we can construct a counterexample if $H$ is crafted with knowledge of $G$, and/or $G$ is of hidden order.